# Simple inheritance tree in XML schema

Tags: xml, inheritance, xsd

I believed to have understand everything in [this article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-flexschema/), but it seems that there is still some work for me.

If I have a simple inheritance tree in my classes:

```
A (abstract)
^
B
^
C
```

And I want to have a simple list of objects in my xml as followes:

```
<mylist>
    <B>lalala</B>
    <C>fofofo</C>
    <C>fofofo</C>
    <C>fofofo</C>
    <C>fofofo</C>
    <B>lalala</B>
</mylist>
```

It doesn't seem to work when I try to validate this scheme against:

```
<xs:schema>
    <xs:complexType name="A" abstract="true">
        <xs:element name="text" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="B">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="A"/>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="C">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="B"/>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:element name="mylist>
        <xs:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:element name="A" type="A"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Remember, this is just pseudo code for the sake of short xmls without a lot of namespaces.

> Why does a validator tell me (notepad++ for example) that it is still expecting an `<A>` and not a `<B>` or a `<C>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting close.  But you're conflating element names with type names.  Types B and C are substitutable for type A, but you haven't declared any elements named B and C at all, let alone declared them and made them substitutable for element A.

The following XML instance is valid against a corrected version of your schema:

```
<mylist xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="Mamix.xsd">
    <A xsi:type="B"><text>lalala</text></A>
    <A xsi:type="C"><text>fofofo</text></A>
    <A xsi:type="C"><text>fofofo</text></A>
    <A xsi:type="C"><text>fofofo</text></A>
    <A xsi:type="C"><text>fofofo</text></A>
    <A xsi:type="B"><text>lalala</text></A>
</mylist>
```

If you want to allow elements B and C instead, declare them with appropriate types and specify that they are substitutable for element A (which must be a top-level element for this to be possible).  Your schema will look like this:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xs:complexType name="A" abstract="true">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="text" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>        
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="B">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="A"/>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="C">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="B"/>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:element name="A" type="A"/>
    <xs:element name="B" type="B" substitutionGroup="A"/>
    <xs:element name="C" type="C" substitutionGroup="A"/>

    <xs:element name="mylist">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:element ref="A"/>
            </xs:sequence>            
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

Against this schema, the following instance (modified from your original XML by adding the 'text' element your declaration for 'A' requires) is valid:

```
<mylist xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="Mamix.xsd">
    <B><text>lalala</text></B>
    <C><text>fofofo</text></C>
    <C><text>fofofo</text></C>
    <C><text>fofofo</text></C>
    <C><text>fofofo</text></C>
    <B><text>lalala</text></B>
</mylist>
```